# An Invalid value None for TO_TIMESTAMP

Tags: sql, postgresql

Not able to perform TO_TIMESTAMP on my date field.

`select TO_TIMESTAMP(  mydate ,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')  as mydate from cte3`

Error Msg.

````
ERROR:  invalid value "None" for "YYYY"
DETAIL:  Value must be an integer.
SQL state: 22007```
````

Comment: (1) What is datatype of `mydate` field? (2) What do you expect your `cast` to achive?

Comment: The error is self explanatory you are trying to run `to_timestamp('None')` and that is not going to work.

Comment: Is this coming out of some Python code? That would help explain the `None`. Best guess is that `None` is not being properly converted to `NULL` and instead the `__repr__ ` is being entered: `None.__repr__()  'None'`.

Comment: @PM77-1 The cast was part of my trial and error. I just removed it :)

Comment: Thank you for your response @AdrianKlaver, how do I resolve it? I attempted `where mydate <> ` and `nullif` None of these worked. And it did not come from python, this is a sql query.

Comment: 1) Per @PM77-1 comment what is data type for `mydate`? 2) How is `None` getting into the field? 3) To your question add the queries you attempted. 4) `select TO_TIMESTAMP(nullif('None', 'None') ,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'); NULL` should work.

Comment: Actually this can be simplified to `select nullif(mydate, 'None')::timestamp;`

Comment: @AdrianKlaver it (select nullif(mydate, 'None')::timestamp;)  worked thank you! Question! how did you acquire this skill? I am new to sql.

Comment: By paying attention to detail and reading the docs. On that note you still have not answered what the data type is for `mydate` and how `None` is getting into it? Assuming `mydate` is some form of string type you have found out why that is a bad idea for storing `timestamp` values.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver you are right that is a string type. I got it, bad design choice at the insertion.

Comment: Yes, *An ounce of prevention is worth a pound of cure*.  Making sure the input data is valid to begin with will save you a lot of work down the road.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Added ben frank's biography to my reading list :)